# Is there a possibility to react on an ajax post which is coming from the destination site of the first ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry for the confusing question above but it is very dificult to formulate.
I want to do following: I do an ajax request (type: "POST", url: "auth.php") from the "index.php" and I send two data objects with it. The site "auth.php" does some interaction with my database and makes an ajax "POST" request back to "index.php". This second post also contains data. And now the question: Is it possible to use the data of the second post back to "index.php" with javascript?

index.php -- post data --> auth.php -- interact with server --> auth.php -- post data --> index.php

Comment: The response of the AJAX request will always be back to the originating page. [read this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) That is the default behavior of AJAX.

Comment: On success callback of the ajax call, perform *another* ajax call inside of it.

Comment: I'll second what @GetSet said. Each post is a separate Ajax request. You can make them at the same time, or if the second depends on the results of the first, you'll have to do them one at a time.